# tiny-warning : "Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: reactjs

I just started a new project using React with Webpack. I keep getting the same error when serving the app.

> Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\workwork\apol2\apol2\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js'
>       at Object. (tiny-warning.esm.js:20)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 73c6a5b3e608efed68ac:19)
>       at Object. (scheduler.development.js:699)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 73c6a5b3e608efed68ac:19)
>       at Object. (index.js:6)
>       at Object. (index.js:7)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap 73c6a5b3e608efed68ac:19)
>       at react-dom.development.js:21
>       at Object. (react-dom.development.js:21277)
>       at Object. (react-dom.development.js:21278)

This is not a package I installed and I don't know where to begin to debug this.. Could it be one of the package I use?

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel ./app -d build",
    "build:watch": "babel ./app -d build --watch",
    "build:client": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js/",
    "build:watch:client": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js/ --watch",
    "build:prod": "npm run build && npm run build:client",
    "start": "npm run build:prod && NODE_ENV=production node ./build/server/index.js",
    "start:dev": "parallelshell \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run build:watch:client\" \"nodemon ./build/server/index.js\"",
    "test": "jest --watch --coverage"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/build/"
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/build/"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 90,
        "functions": 90,
        "lines": 90,
        "statements": 90
      }
    },
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>setupTests.js"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.0-beta2",
    "parallelshell": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "scheduler": "^0.16.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.5",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After deleting my folder node_modules several times between my tests, the error disapeared...

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is not installed, make sure install webpack or do **npm install**